# Congruence definitions equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, congruences

We say that $x$ is congruent to $y$ modulo $z$ when $$x\equiv y\pmod z \iff x \pmod z = y \pmod z$$

Another definition is $$\quad x \equiv y \pmod z \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: x - y = k z$$

Why are those definitions equivalent? The second one says there exists $k$ such tkat $x=y+kz$. It means $x \pmod z = (y + kz)\pmod z$ = $y$. And conversely, if we write $y$ as $y=x-kz$, then $y \pmod z = (x - kz)\pmod z$ = $x$. So $x$ and $y$ are congruent if they are equal.

Where's the mistake in my reasoning? And how to prove the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: Why do you suppose that $x\pmod{z} = x$? (I assume by mod here you mean the smallest positive remainder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake in your reasoning $(y+kz) \pmod{z}$ in fact equals $y \pmod{z}$ (which may not equal $y$); and similarly for $x-kz$.

To show the definitions are equivalent:

The first definition says that $x$ and $y$ leave the same remainder upon division by $z$.  So $x=zq_1+r$ and $y=zq_2+r$ for some integers $q_1,q_2,r$ with $0\le r<z$.  Then $x-y=z(q_1-q_2)$, and so the second definition holds.

Conversely the second definition says that $x-y=kz$; and so if for instance $y=zq+r$ (division algorithm), then $x=z(q+k)+r$, which is the same remainder.  So the first definition holds.

Comment: What book do you recommend which is a good, easy to understand (but thorough, with proofs) introduction into this topic?

Comment: I am not current on what's coming out these days in Number Theory, but I have liked Dudley's number theory book, and Rosen's.

Comment: I'm wondering why in every book congruence is defined using the first definition. The second definition is intuitive and obvious. By looking at the first one it tells me nothing at all.

Comment: @user4205580: I don't know the definitive answer to the implied question in your comment.  However, the first definition is often stated in the form $x\equiv y \pmod{z}$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ leave the same remainder upon division by $z$.  With this definition it then becomes super easy to show that congruence $\pmod{z}$ is an equivalence relation on the integers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first definition is obvious ($x\equiv y\pmod z \iff x \pmod z = y \pmod z$).

Comment: Well the second definition is nice because it gives you an easier test for congruence: is the difference divisible by $z$ (usually easier than finding both remainders separately--two divisions).

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct:

$x-y = kz$ does not imply

$$x \pmod z = (y + kz) \pmod z = y$$ if you use $a \pmod 3$ as notation for the positive division remainder. (In maths, this notations is usually used for congruence classes, not remainders!)

E.g. for $x=1$,$y=-2$,$z=3$:

$1-(-2) = 1\cdot 3$

$1 \pmod 3 = -2+1\cdot 3 \pmod 3 = 1 \pmod 3 \neq -2$